# How to use mkdir for nested directories

Tags: bash, sed, mkdir

I have the following variable that shows where I should write my report to
`REPORT="ZFS(~/Q4Y22/report/q4y22.md)"`

I have used `sed`to extract the path and `dirname` command to get the
`~/Q4Y22/report/`dir name which I assign to `reportdir` variable.

However when I run the following test, instead of the Q4Y22 dir being created in my home dir, it literally creates the following directory hierachy `~/Q4Y22/report` inside my home for example `farai/~/Q4Y22/report` instead of `farai/Q4Y22/report`

```
if [ -d $reportdir ]
then
    echo "dir exists, keep moving"   
else
    mkdir -p $reportdir
fi
```

How do I get around this, I tried using sed to remove the tilde from the path but i was wondering if there is a more clever way

Comment: `~` isn't processed after expanding variables.

Comment: It works as intended for me in Ubuntu docker image. Also notice that you don't have to check if a directory exists when using `-p` with mkdir because it'll not error out if directory already exists.

Comment: You have set `reportdir` incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

My try on this:

```
#!/bin/bash
REPORT="~/Q4Y22/report/q4y22.md"
reportdir=$(dirname "${REPORT/'~'/$HOME}")
if [ -d "$reportdir" ]
then
    echo "dir exists, keep moving"   
else
    mkdir -p "$reportdir"
fi
```

This is a bit fragile since you could have `~` in the filename, though, but you could improve this script to replace only the first char if it's a tilde.

Comment: `realpath` doesn't expand `~`.

Comment: They said that they're getting `reportdir` by extracting it from the `REPORT` variable.

Comment: The tilde is being expanded by the shell before passing it to realpath. Try `realpath '~'`

Comment: Notice that it left the literal `~` in the output.

Comment: It's resolving it as a literal name relative to the current directory, it's not converting it to `$HOME`.

Comment: You were right on your comments regarding what I wrote first, thanks. Take a look at the edited answer.

Comment: Instead of manually replacing the tilde, why don't you set set `REPORT=~/Q4Y22/report/q4y22.md` (without quotes, so that ~ gets expanded by bash), or `REPORT="$HOME/Q4Y22/report/q4y22.md"`, which also would do the same?

Comment: @user1934428 if he can modify the variable definition, that's a better option indeed (my first answer did something similar).